# The lifetimes of a colour TV picture tube

Tags: probability

The lifetimes of a color TV picture tube is normally distributed, with a mean of $8$ years and a standard deviation of $2$ years.

(i) What is the probability that a picture tube will last more than $10$ years?

(ii) If the firm guarantees the picture tube for $4$ years, what percentage of the tubes sold will have to be replaced?

Comment: What have you tried so far. These are pretty easy questions, and you should be able to make the first few steps

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Comment: Why the question get vote down? Maybe it is easy for us, but not for him. At least, if we don't like it, just ignore it.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey:  Because that's not how this site works.  This is obvious homework without even an attempt to do it.

Comment: @nomen I just try to be nice since he/she is a newbie here. As I said in my previous comment, "if we don't like it, just ignore it" or you can ask like what Mathias711 did in his comment.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey:  but ignoring it undermines the purpose of the site.  I think the down-votes are necessary (though I usually put a comment like drhab's if I do down-vote, explaining why).  I appreciate your point about being nice.

Answer (score 1):

(i): You want to look at the integral from 10 to infinity of the normal distribution (with mean=8, deviation = 2), because then you have the chance for a TV to last more then 10 years.
$$
\int_{10}^{\infty}\text{ NormalDistribution}[8,2] = 0.1587
$$
(ii): The same goes for the second question, but now you are interested in a lower limit. You take the integral from -inifinity (not 0, because normal distributions dont account for physically impossible answers) up until 4, because that is the age a tv can be, without being replaced.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{4}\text{ NormalDistribution}[8,2] = 0.02275
$$

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, let's brush up this thing first. If the random variable $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, in statistical term we call $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, then the random variable
$$
Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
will have a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, in statistical term we call $Z$ has standard normal distribution, $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. The transformation is needed in this case to make it easy for us to check its probability by using standard normal or $Z$ table.

Now, let $X$ be a random variable that denotes the lifetimes of a color TV picture tube and $X\sim\mathcal{N}(8,2)$. Therefore

- The probability that a picture tube will last more than 10 years is
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \text{Pr}[X > 10]&=\text{Pr}\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}>\frac{10-8}{2}\right]\\
  &=\text{Pr}[Z>1]\\
  &=1-\text{Pr}[Z\le1]\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{check its value using $Z$ table}\\
  &\approx1-0.8413\\
  &=0.15867.
  \end{align}
  $$
- The tubes sold will have to be replaced if the tubes broke less than $4$ years since the picture tubes have been purchased. Thus
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \text{Pr}[X\le 4]&=\text{Pr}\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le\frac{4-8}{2}\right]\\
  &=\text{Pr}[Z\le -2]\\
  &=0.02275.
  \end{align}
  $$

I hope this help. Next time if you want to ask again here, let us know what is your effort first to answer your question and then we would be happy to help you. **:)**

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$